# Изменение одного div-а при наведении курсором на кнопку

Tags: javascript, html

Есть код который работает скриптом в HTML. Как его поместить в отдельный файл js и привязать к html, чтобы он дальше работал?

```js
  $('#change-btn-basic').hover(
      function(){
          $('#change-basic').css('background-color','$active-color');
      },
      function(){
          $('#change-basic').css('background-color','#485460');
      }
  );
  $('#change-btn-pro').hover(
      function(){
          $('#change-pro').css('background-color','$active-color');
      },
      function(){
          $('#change-pro').css('background-color','#485460');
      }
  );
  $('#change-btn-premium').hover(
      function(){
          $('#change-premium').css('background-color','$active-color');
      },
      function(){
          $('#change-premium').css('background-color','#485460');
      }
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

Надо добавить скрипт в отдельный файл например `script.js`

А потом в вашем файле с `html` разметкой подключить его так.

```
<script src="`здесь надо писать путь к файлу`/script.js"></script>
```

И прикрепить этот скрипт правильно в теге `<head>`.

```
<html>
    <head>

        <script src="`здесь надо писать путь к файлу`/script.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Здесь какой то код -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ага, а потом у человека всё перестанет работать, ибо вы поместили `<script>` в `<head>`. Плюс ещё нужно не забыть упомянуть, что подключение этого скрипта должно быть после подключения jQuery.